# Show sorted Icon on sorting in angularJS using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am not able to show proper icon on sorting of column, if I click of one column for sorting  then icons of all other columns also gets updated.

Only sorted column should get update on sorting of respective column.

I have listed my code here : http://plnkr.co/edit/UonOgNz0s16iKJkWLwyg?p=preview

### HTML Code :

```
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(colors[0])" ng-click="ctrl.predicate = key; ctrl.reverse=!ctrl.reverse;">
          {{key}}
          <span class="fa fa-sort columnSortIcons" ng-if="ctrl.reverse"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-sort-down columnSortIcons" ng-if="!(ctrl.reverse)"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-sort-up columnSortIcons" ng-if="ctrl.reverse"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(colors[0])">
          <input type="text" ng-model="search[key]" />
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in colors | filter:search | orderBy:ctrl.predicate:ctrl.reverse">
        <td ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(item)">{{item[key]}}</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

### JS Code :

```
  this.predicate='id';
  this.reverse=false;

  $scope.search = {};

  $scope.colors = [{
    'id': 1,
    'productId': 1001,
    'productName': 'prd 1',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-01T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'productId': 1002,
    'productName': 'prd 2',
    'minimumLevel': 23,
    'price': 12.54,
    'productDate': '2014-11-02T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'productId': 1003,
    'productName': 'prd 3',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-04T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'productId': 1004,
    'productName': 'prd 4',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-22T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 5,
    'productId': 1005,
    'productName': 'prd 5',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-18T06:41:30.809Z'
  }];

  $scope.getKeysOfCollection = function(obj) {
    obj = angular.copy(obj);
    if (!obj) {
      return [];
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ng-if` statements you aren't checking to see if that column is the sorted column (the predicate):

```
<span class="fa fa-sort-down columnSortIcons" ng-if="!(ctrl.reverse) && key == ctrl.predicate"></span>
<span class="fa fa-sort-up columnSortIcons" ng-if="ctrl.reverse && key == ctrl.predicate"></span>
```

Updated [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcgUMOxFDkPz6fQ0YAvD?p=preview).

Comment: I'm running this with the given answer , I'm unable to see any updown arrows in the headers, is anything besides this is needed..where as the same is visible in plnkr

Comment: @ArunKumarMudraboyina, I'm sorry to hear that, but without knowing any details about **your code**, I'm not sure how you expect help.

Comment: I've posted a question for this..please see here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43258840/sorting-up-down-icons-are-not-visible-in-angularjs-using-ng-repeat