# Sorting up/down icons are not visible in angularJs using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm able to sort the table data on click event of table headers. But unable to see the up/down icon accordingly. I picked this code from here.[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcgUMOxFDkPz6fQ0YAvD?p=preview)
This is fine when I'm executing this code in plnkr where as the same is not working 
in my browser. I checked this in both Firefox and chrome. Please let me know where I'm doing wrong. here is  the code..

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  Predicate: {{ctrl.predicate}}
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(colors[0])" ng-click="ctrl.predicate = key; ctrl.reverse=!ctrl.reverse;">
          {{key}}
          <!--<span class="fa fa-sort columnSortIcons" ng-if="ctrl.reverse && key == ctrl.predicate"></span>-->
          <span class="fa fa-sort-down columnSortIcons" ng-if="!(ctrl.reverse) && key == ctrl.predicate"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-sort-up columnSortIcons" ng-if="ctrl.reverse && key == ctrl.predicate"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(colors[0])">
          <input type="text" ng-model="search[key]" />
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in colors | filter:search | orderBy:ctrl.predicate:ctrl.reverse">
        <td ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(item)">{{item[key]}}</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.predicate='id';
  this.reverse=false;

  $scope.search = {};

  $scope.colors = [{
    'id': 1,
    'productId': 1001,
    'productName': 'arun',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-01T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'productId': 1002,
    'productName': 'kumar',
    'minimumLevel': 23,
    'price': 12.54,
    'productDate': '2014-11-02T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'productId': 1003,
    'productName': 'banu',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-04T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'productId': 1004,
    'productName': 'ravi',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-22T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 5,
    'productId': 1005,
    'productName': 'sri',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-18T06:41:30.809Z'
  }];

  $scope.getKeysOfCollection = function(obj) {
    obj = angular.copy(obj);
    if (!obj) {
      return [];
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
  }
});
```

Result:
My result is like below.. not showing up/down icons while clicking on headers.
[image]

Comment: check this. http://plnkr.co/edit/uJMU710XjHZJ8D32sTCS?p=preview

Comment: The logic all checks out. What I think may be happening is that your css stylesheet isn't making it. Can you verify that your styles are being applied to the arrows by removing the if condition? If they still don't show up, the style sheet is missing

Comment: @Cameron, I downloaded that font-awesome.css and link my view to this css locally. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.css">. But still issue not resolved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved by changing below line.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
```

It is making sense that, even though the url locating font-awesome.css, but for href,it is required to tell protocol(http) to locate the css file from web.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use ng-show instead ng-if

```html
 <span class="fa fa-sort-down columnSortIcons" ng-show="!(ctrl.reverse) && key == ctrl.predicate"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-sort-up columnSortIcons" ng-show="ctrl.reverse && key == ctrl.predicate"></span>
```